# Minimise absolute values of weighted sum of numbers

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming, operations-research

Part of my problem is to minimise the absolute value of the weighted sum of certain numbers. I have to find the weights.

Let's say I have a set of numbers A, a1, a2, a3 and a4, such that(a1, a2 > 0), (a3, a4 < 0)

Minimum weight is, say, 0.1 (10%), maximum is 0.4 (40%). I am looking for weights **w** in such a way that the weighted sum is zero; if zero is not possible, then the closest possible to zero. A simple linear model can be used to achieve this:

```
Minimise E

E >= SUM w * a
E >= -(SUM w * a)
SUM w = 1
w >= 0.1 for all w
w <= 0.4 for all w
```

A simple linear program is enough to find the solution very fast. However, I would very much like to find a polynomial algorithm or formula for this problem. Any ideas? Is this problem well known?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimizing (resp. maximizing) `SUM w * a` is easy; set all weights to the minimum and then from the least a to the greatest (resp. greatest to least) increase the weight respecting the local maximum until the global maximum is achieved.

If the [min, max] interval contains 0, then an optimal solution can be realized as a convex combination of these two solutions. Otherwise, take the solution closer to 0.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I'll try that out and come back to comment on it.

Answer (score 1):

The [ellipsoid algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Ellipsoid_algorithm.2C_following_Khachiyan) was the first worst-case polynomial-time algorithm for linear programming.

However, I suspect you want to solve your problem fast, that is why you are interested in a polynomial-time algorithm.

In that case, you will be better off with the **simplex method**. Even though the simplex is exponential in the worst case, it seems to be the best choice for most practical applications. Not surprisingly, it is implemented in all the good quality solvers that I know of.

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks for your answer, but actually I already solve it very fast with simplex. The issue here is not that I want to solve it faster, I simply want to check i fI can come up with a specialized algorithm to solve this problem without resorting to a linear programming model

Comment: OK, I see. And what is the reason for avoiding the linear programming model? You do not want an LP solver in your application as a dependecy?

Comment: Actually my intentions are more to have it as a mathematical proof of how easy the problem is.

Comment: Then, perhaps you would have better luck with this question at [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/) or at [scicomp.stackexchange.com](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The math.stackexchange.com has high traffic. Your question is perhaps better suited for scicomp.stackexchange.com but that site has lower traffic. Good luck!